# Passing a string value from c# file to js file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass a string value from c# file to js file.

If I try to pass an int value, then I can pass it, but I am unable to pass string value.

```
string value = "abc";
 int a=5;
 TableCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "F1("+value +")"); //NOTHING HAPPENS
 TableCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "F1("+a +")"); //Works Perfectly
```

js file

```
function F1(value) {
    alert(value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass string value in quotes `''`

*Use*

```
TableCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "F1('"+value +"')"); 
                                        ^          ^
```

Otherwise it treated as variable. Currently you must be getting error in browser console.

Comment: No *don't* just put the value in single quotes. Currently this will break if the value contains single quotes itself, or a backslash for example. The value needs to be escaped as well as quoted.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Completely agree

Answer (score 4):

Consider what your HTML will look like.

First version:

```
onclick="F1(abc)"
```

Second version:

```
onclick="F1(5)"
```

Clearly the second version is passing the value `5`. The first version is passing the value of `abc` - whatever that is, within the context of the Javascript you're executing.

You *could* quote the string, making sure that you escape quotes etc - I'm assuming that in reality, your value is fetched dynamically from somewhere, and you might not have much control over the content. Hopefully there's something within whatever ASP.NET version you're using that will let you do that, such as [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode).

For example, to get the string `abc` in your call, you want the attribute to be:

```
onclick="F1('abc')"
```

but if to get the string `I don't know` in your call, you want the attribute to be:

```
onclick="F1('I don\'t know')"
```

The key is to look at the generated HTML - pretend you're the browser, and look at the world from *its* perspective. Once you've worked out what HTML you want to generate, writing the code to do so is often relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding single-quotes around the value when building it in your C# string. In your first scenario, the Js is receiving:

```
F1(abc);
```

Which it reads as being the variable abc. Try adding single quotes (and it's probably best to use string.format, BTW):

```
TableCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("F1('{0}')", value));
```

Comment: There's no *particular* benefit in using `string.Format` here (what makes you say it's "probably best"?) - but it *would* be important to escape any quotes etc within the value.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the string, it would produce the JavaScript code `F1(abc)`. That would interpret `abc` as a variable name, not a string literal.

Add apostrophes around the string to make it a string literal:

```
TableCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "F1('" + value + "')");
```

If the string can contain apostrophes or backslashes, you would need to escape them:

```
TableCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "F1('" + value.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("'", "\\'") + "')");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will take care of escaping any special characters (i.e. quotes, etc...)

```
TableCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "F1('"+HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(value)+"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a string through the argument, you need either " or ' characters to delimit it. Your variable name is translating to (adb) in the call. ("adb") or ('adb') would be the string value.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it will print

```
F1(abc)
```

So it will look for a variable called `abc`.

You should use

```
TableCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "F1(\""+value +"\")");
```

So the output will be

```
F1("abc")
```

Comment: Except that as per other answers including mine, you need to be careful about escaping the value - just quoting it may well not be enough.